# batch script keeps giving error code 3 even through it is work as intended

Tags: batch-file, tfs, tfs-2015, windows-server-2012

This script keeps giving me error code 3 for the robocopy but is working as intended. I created a log file to capture it and it runs just fine in command line and in script but I still get an error on My Build in TFS 2015. Any ideas?

TFS build error :

> Exception Message: TF270015: 'RolltoDEV.bat' returned an unexpected
>   exit code. Expected '0'; actual '3'.

here is my script:

```
@echo off
set root="D:\Drop\PythonAutomation\1-DEV\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV"
CD /D %root% 
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET a=%%i
CD /D C:\

robocopy "C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation" "D:\Drop\PythonAutomation\1-DEV\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV\%a%" /E /log:D:\logFileForPython.txt

robocopy "C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation" "D:\PythonAutomation" /E /log+:D:\logFileForPython.txt
```

Here is the log file:

> > -------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
>
> ---
>
> Started : Monday, October 2, 2017 11:04:27 AM    Source :
>   C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\
>        Dest : D:\Drop\PythonAutomation\1-DEV\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV_20171002.23\
>
> ```
> Files : *.*
>      Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>                  3    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\  *EXTRA Dir        -1    D:\Drop\PythonAutomation\1-DEV\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV_20171002.23\logs\
>   New File            1324    PythonAutomation.log   0%   100%  
>   New File            1255    PythonAutomation.sln   0%   100%  
>   New File             221    PythonAutomation.sln.Any CPU.Debug.vsprops   0%   100%        New Dir
> ```
>
> 1 C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\
>         New File            3552    PythonAutomation.pyproj   0%   100%       New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD
>   to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\BaseObjects\       New Dir
>   1 C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Configuration\
>         New File             374    Config-Main.py   0%   100%        New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Configuration\Properties\
>   New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation -
>   CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Configuration\Properties\PublishProfiles\
>       New Dir          1    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation
>   - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Configuration\Properties\PublishProfiles\RolltoDEV\
>         New File             520    RolltoDEV.bat   0%   100%         New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Properties\       New Dir
>   0 C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\     New Dir
>   4 C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\BaseObjects\
>         New File            2664    Email.py   0%   100%
>         New File             573    File.py   0%   100%
>         New File            1260    SSHConnection.py   0%   100%
>         New File             342    **init**.py   0%   100%       New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Properties\
>       New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation
>   - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Properties\PublishProfiles\
>       New Dir          3    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation
>   - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Properties\PublishProfiles\PublishProfiles\
>         New File             864    RolltoDEV.pubxml   0%   100%
>         New File             934    RolltoPROD.pubxml   0%   100%
>         New File             922    RolltoQA.pubxml   0%   100%
>
> ---
>
> ```
>            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
> Dirs :        13        12         0         0         0         1    Files :        13        13         0         0         0         0
> ```
>
> Bytes :    14.4 k    14.4 k         0         0         0         0
>   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
>   Ended : Monday, October 2, 2017 11:04:27 AM
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
>
> ---
>
> Started : Monday, October 2, 2017 11:04:27 AM    Source :
>   C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\
>        Dest : D:\PythonAutomation\
>
> ```
> Files : *.*
>      Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>                  3    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\  *EXTRA Dir        -1    D:\PythonAutomation\.vs\    *EXTRA Dir        -1    D:\PythonAutomation\Outputs\
>   New File            1324    PythonAutomation.log   0%   100%  
>   New File            1255    PythonAutomation.sln   0%   100%  
>   New File             221    PythonAutomation.sln.Any CPU.Debug.vsprops   0%   100%        New Dir
> ```
>
> 1 C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\
>         New File            3552    PythonAutomation.pyproj   0%   100%       New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD
>   to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\BaseObjects\       New Dir
>   1 C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Configuration\
>         New File             374    Config-Main.py   0%   100%        New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Configuration\Properties\
>   New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation -
>   CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Configuration\Properties\PublishProfiles\
>       New Dir          1    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation
>   - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Configuration\Properties\PublishProfiles\RolltoDEV\
>         New File             520    RolltoDEV.bat   0%   100%         New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Properties\       New Dir
>   0 C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\     New Dir
>   4 C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\BaseObjects\
>         New File            2664    Email.py   0%   100%
>         New File             573    File.py   0%   100%
>         New File            1260    SSHConnection.py   0%   100%
>         New File             342    **init**.py   0%   100%       New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation - CD to
>   DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Properties\
>       New Dir          0    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation
>   - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Properties\PublishProfiles\
>       New Dir          3    C:\Builds\1004\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation
>   - CD to DEV\src\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\PythonAutomation\Properties\PublishProfiles\PublishProfiles\
>         New File             864    RolltoDEV.pubxml   0%   100%
>         New File             934    RolltoPROD.pubxml   0%   100%
>         New File             922    RolltoQA.pubxml   0%   100%
>
> ---
>
> ```
>            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
> Dirs :        13        12         0         0         0         2    Files :        13        13         0         0         0         0
> ```
>
> Bytes :    14.4 k    14.4 k         0         0         0         0
>   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
>
> Speed :             1057500 Bytes/sec.    Speed :
>   60.510 MegaBytes/min.    Ended : Monday, October 2, 2017 11:04:27 AM

Comment: See this link https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html    0×03   3       (2+1) Some files were copied. Additional files were present. No failure was encountered.

Comment: Thanks for the help! See my answer below on what I did with this information. @RGuggisberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may run into this issue, since the error wasn't really an error in the batch script it was still working but in TFS an error message is an error message so it failed. What I did to fix this issue is to bypass this specific error in my batch script by adding the following code to the end of my robocopy statements.

```
2>&1|find /v "TF270015"
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. Thanks to [@RGuggisburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2093352/rguggisberg) for showing me the real error message behind 3.